# Copy VBA code from a Sheet in one workbook to another?

Tags: vba, excel, vbe

I've been using the lines below to compy VBA modules from one workbook to another and I don't know if there is an easier way, but they have been working fine:

```
Set srcVba = srcWbk.VBProject
Set srcModule = srcVba.VBComponents(moduleName)

srcModule.Export (path) 'Export from source
trgtVba.VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=trgtVba.VBComponents.Item(moduleName) 'Remove from target
trgtVba.VBComponents.Import (path) 'Import to target
```

However now I need to copy VBA code that is in a Sheet, not in a Module. The above method doesn't work for that scenario.

What code can I use to copy VBA code in a sheet from one workbook to another?

Comment: Just copy the Sheet.  The code will come along with it.

Comment: I don't want to copy the sheet, I only want to copy the VBA code!

Comment: Usually the code in a Sheet, *needs* to be in the Sheet, it's just written that way. (otherwise, why put the code in a Sheet in the first place?)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't remove and re-import the `VBComponent`, since that would logically delete the whole worksheet. Instead you have to use `CodeModule` to manipulate the text within the component:

```
Dim src As CodeModule, dest As CodeModule

Set src = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule
Set dest = Workbooks("Book3").VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook") _
    .CodeModule

dest.DeleteLines 1, dest.CountOfLines
dest.AddFromString src.Lines(1, src.CountOfLines)
```

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant! How can I become as good at VBA as you? Can you tell me your favorite books or sources from which you have learned most?

Comment: Oh, this is just coming from a few weeks of scattered work trying to solve that same exact problem. The only thing I could do was poke and prod at the VBA extensibility objects until I found some methods that vaguely sounded like what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else lands here searching for VSTO equivalent of Chel's answer, here it is:

```
void CopyMacros(Workbook src, Workbook dest)
{
  var srcModule = src.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(1).CodeModule;
  var destModule = dest.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

  destModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(srcModule.Lines[1, srcModule.CountOfLines]);
}
```

Things to note:

1. You must add reference to **Microsoft.Vbe.Interop** to do this stuff.
2. I'm adding a new general module to the destination workbook, so I didn't need to call `DeleteLines`. YMMV.

Comment: Anyone looking to do this in .Net generally can also look at the source code for my [VBA Sync Tool](https://github.com/chelh/VBASync)

Answer (score 1):

Patrick's code does not work for Worksheets (in fact, it will transfer the code to the wrong module). A workaround is to create a new sheet in the destination workbook, and then copy the code over (optionally you can copy and paste the worksheet data/functions/formatting as well).

The other thing that doesn't work is UserForms. You can copy the code over, but I'm not aware of any way to copy the actual form (including all the controls) without using the export/import method.

Expanding on Patrick's code:

```
'Needs reference to : Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3 ,
'or run this code : thisworkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
'from immediate window (ctrl+G) or create a small sub

' What works:   Successfully tranfsers Modules with code and name
'               Copies userform code and name only, but the form is blank (does not transfer controls)
'               Copies code in sheets but no content (optionally add code to copy & paste content)
'               Successfully transfers Classes with code and name

Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyComponentsModules() 'copies sheets/Thisworkbook/Userforms/Modules/Classes to a new workbook
    Dim src As CodeModule, dest As CodeModule
    Dim i&
    Dim WB_Dest As Workbook
    Dim Ref As Reference
    Dim Comp As VBComponent
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Debug.Print "Starting"

    Set WB_Dest = Application.Workbooks.Add
    On Error Resume Next 'needed for testing if component already exists in destination WorkBook and for cross-references
        For Each Comp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
            Debug.Print Comp.Name & " - "; Comp.Type
            Err.Clear
            'Set Source code module
            Set src = Comp.CodeModule  'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule

            'Test if destination component exists first
            i = 0
            i = Len(WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents(Comp.Name).Name)
            If i <> 0 Then 'or: if err=0 then
                Set dest = WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents(Comp.Name).CodeModule
            Else 'create component
                Err.Clear
                If Comp.Type = 100 Then
                    Set sht = WB_Dest.Sheets.Add
                    Set dest = WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents(sht.Name).CodeModule
                    WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents(sht.Name).Name = Comp.Name
                    sht.Name = Comp.Name
                Else
                    With WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(Comp.Type)
                        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                            MsgBox "Error: Component " & Comp.Name & vbCrLf & Err.Description
                        Else
                            .Name = Comp.Name
                            Set dest = .CodeModule
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            End If

            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                'copy module/Form/Sheet/Class 's code:
                dest.DeleteLines 1, dest.CountOfLines
                dest.AddFromString src.Lines(1, src.CountOfLines)
            End If
        Next Comp

        'Add references as well :
        For Each Ref In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
            WB_Dest.VBProject.References.AddFromFile Ref.FullPath
        Next Ref

    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

    Set Ref = Nothing
    Set src = Nothing
    Set dest = Nothing
    Set Comp = Nothing
    Set WB_Dest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a compiled code from different sources as well from this very one Post.
My contribution is a code that copies ALL your codes from VBE (Sheets/Thisworkbook/Userforms/Modules/Classes) to a new Workbook.

i created this , because i have a corrupt workbook and making a code to recover all that isn't corrupt, including code. (this part only recovers code + references) :

```
'needs a reference to : Visual basic for Application Extensibility 5.3 ,
'or run this code : thisworkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
'from immediate window (ctrl+G) or create a small sub

Option Explicit

Sub CopyComponentsModules() 'copies sheets/Thisworkbook/Userforms/Modules/Classes  to a new workbook
Dim src As CodeModule, dest As CodeModule
Dim i&
Dim WB_Dest As Workbook
'Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Comp As VBComponent

'Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'sh.Cells.Clear

Set WB_Dest = Application.Workbooks.Add
On Error Resume Next 'needed for testing if component already exists in destination WorkBook and for cross-references.
For Each Comp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents

            'i = i + 1
            'sh.Cells(i, 1).Value = Comp.Name

            'Set Source code module
            Set src = Comp.CodeModule  'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet1").CodeModule

            'test if destination component exists first
            i = 0: i = Len(WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents(Comp.Name).Name)
            If i <> 0 Then 'or: if err=0 then
                Set dest =     WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents(Comp.Name).CodeModule
            Else 'create component
                With WB_Dest.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(Comp.Type)
                    .Name = Comp.Name
                    Set dest = .CodeModule
                End With
            End If

            'copy module/Form/Sheet/Class 's code:
            dest.DeleteLines 1, dest.CountOfLines
            dest.AddFromString src.Lines(1, src.CountOfLines)

Next Comp

'Add references as well :
Dim Ref As Reference
For Each Ref In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
    'Debug.Print Ref.Name 'Nom
    WB_Dest.VBProject.References.AddFromFile Ref.FullPath
    'Debug.Print Ref.FullPath 'Chemin complet
    'Debug.Print Ref.Description 'Description de la référence
    'Debug.Print Ref.IsBroken 'Indique si la référence est manquante
    'Debug.Print Ref.Major & "." & Ref.Minor 'Version
    'Debug.Print "---"
Next Ref

Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0

'WB_Dest.Activate

Set Ref = Nothing
Set src = Nothing
Set dest = Nothing
Set Comp = Nothing
Set WB_Dest = Nothing
End Sub
```