# How to import a class module (.CLS) into Sheet1 instead of class modules

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is a rare question. I exported Sheet1 as .cls (because it was the only option) and when I import it, it shows up in class modules, and I cannot run them anymore. Anyways, is there a way to get the .cls file to be exported into Microsoft  Excel Objects (Sheet1)?

[image: Capture]

Comment: Import it as a class and then copy paste the code from the class into your desired worksheet and then delete the class.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank for your comment. I know I can do this, but I am looking maybe for a way to import it directly into Excel Objects, if there is any.

Comment: Direkt import is not possible in VBE. • Because the code is tied to a specific worksheet and if you import the VBE cannot know for which sheet the code is.

Comment: Could you not modify your code so that it sits in a module and then reference is from your worksheet?

Comment: @Zac Actually that approach won't work with eg events I think (they must remain in the worksheets scope). And anything that is not an event should already be an a module anyway.

Comment: Just import the worksheet (aka copy from original book).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the answer to this is: There is no way to directly import VBA code into a worksheet scope in VBE.

Therefore your options are:

- Import it as class and manually copy paste the code to the desired worksheet and delete the class afterwards
- Import/Move the complete worksheet into your workbook. This will also include the VBA code.
- Write your own import routine in VBA to replace the existing code in a worksheet with the one you like to import: See [Copy VBA code from a Sheet in one workbook to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497527/copy-vba-code-from-a-sheet-in-one-workbook-to-another)

The issue here is that you have to see the worksheet and its VBA code as one union. They cannot exist separately. If you export the VBA code of a worksheet the union gets split and you cannot join them anymore (they don't know they belong to each other).